# Chrome Android does not Autofill Basic password

Tags: chrome-for-android, password, authentication, auto-fill

I have noticed recently that Chrome for Android does not autofill passwords on Basic HTTP authentication pages.

For example, if I navigate to https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/Bijan/Password on Chrome and save the password, it works perfectly. Navigating back to the same page autofills the password.

On Chrome for Android, I verify that the password is saved. However, navigating to the same page from my phone, does not autofill the password.

Is this a bug for anyone else? Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facing the same problem for a 2-3 weeks already. Seems like a bug.

Here's what i found:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1507118

Comment: Thank you! It looks like the current workaround is to go to `chrome://flags/` and disable #filling-across-affiliated-websites-android.

Comment: Same Issue, can confirm the workaround works